# Table columns to be fixed width no matter what content?

Tags: html, xhtml

When I create a table with two colums and start inputting data on one side the other side gets smaller and vice versa.

I've set the table rows to be 50% width and it still does this.

How do I stop them from changing size and stay 50% widht of their container?

Thanks

Comment: try setting the width of the table in pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#table
{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

where "table" is the id of the table

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property `table-layout: fixed;` should take care of this. Also, make sure you're not running in Quirks Mode (that is, add a correct DOCTYPE specification to your HTML document).

Comment: so set them to 50% tr and then table style="table-layout: fixed;" ?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
<table border="1">
    <col width=100>
    <col width=100>
<tr>
    <td>row 1, cell 101234</td>
    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>​
```